# Sessions or cookies across multiplet tabs in PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies

Is it possible to set session variables or cookies that will exist across all tabs?

I thought firefox kept session across all existing tabs, however im testing and finding that only the current tab where the session was originally set is the session available.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Tab 1:

```
setcookie("testcookie", "something", time()+(60*60*24*365));
```

Tab 2:

```
print_r($_COOKIE['testcookie']);
```

Tab 2 only prints an empty array.  If I move this to tab 1, it will print out the cookie.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cookies are always sent to the server providing that:

- The domain matches (including sub-domain).
- The path matches (cookies can be assigned to specific path -- assigning them to root means the entire domain).
- The port matches.
- The protocol (http/https) matches if you set the cookie as secure.

As long as all those things are true, you should have your cookie / cookie based session on all tabs. You will need to refresh the tab in order to see any effects of the cookie (including seeing it in Javascript of Firefox extensions).

If all those are true and you are still not seeing your cookie on all tabs then you have a lot of debugging to do... that is not standard behavior.

Comment: This is what I thought, however I'm setting cookies on one tab and on the other it's not available - see edit

Comment: But if you refresh the page in the same tab that set the cookie then the print_r works? Do you have incognito mode or some privacy extension install? You may want to try it on a different computer with a fresh install of Firefox if you can... just to rule things out.

Comment: Ok I've got it working now.  I'm using CodeIgniter framework, if I use the Cookie Helper, it works, however I MUST specify the 'domain' parameter, otherwise it won't work across tabs.

Answer (score 1):

When i test with the code you show in your edit i have no problems at all...

A few things you could try is:

- Clear all cookies from firefox and run again (if you've  set the cookie before but with other settings the browser sometimes get confused...
- Try with another browser, or on another computer.
- set path of the cookie to "/" and optionally domain to .youdomain.com like this `setcookie("testcookie", "something", time()+(60*60*24*365), "/", ".yourdomain.com");`

If you still cant make it work, my best bet would be cleaning up the server, possibly with a fresh install of PHP and Apache.

Answer (score 0):

To have a universal storage, go with a cookie.

Cookies are Client Side
Session is Server Side

Comment: Well, both are actually client side.

Comment: And cookies aren't available via other tabs either.